# Adobe TypeKit not displaying correctly in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, typekit

I'm having an issue with Adobe TypeKit in IE9. I'm attempting to load the Proxima Nova font, however in IE9 it's:

- Not displaying the font
- Getting an incorrect font-weight
- Displaying in italics

**IE9 (Incorrect):**

[image: Screenshot from IE9]

**Firefox (Correct):**

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]

It works in every other browser (including earlier versions of IE), just not IE9. I couldn't find any mention of this problem using Google - are there any known issues with TypeKit or IE9 that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found the root of the problem - one of our PHP scripts was calling in a comment before the Doctype declaration:

```
<!-- Example -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This error was preventing TypeKit from functionally normally, and removing it fixed the issue.